# How to map HSCAN response to Map<key, value> using Vert.x Redis

Tags: java, redis, quarkus, vert.x

I am using `io.quarkus.redis.client.RedisClient` which inside use [Vert.x](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-redis-client/java/) for a Redis Client in Java. When I use HSCAN method it return a list of key and values in differents rows like this:

[image]

The keys are 0,2,4... and the values are the JSONs. Is there a way to obtain a Map<key,value> instead of a list with a key and values mix in a elegant/clean way?

Comment: If you can change the library then using https://lettuce.io/ is ideal since it returns a Map. Or you could manually make a Map out of the list.

Comment: I need to use the Quarkus one. I can do manually but is not going to be a elegant way. What is your recommendation?

Comment: I went through the documentation but unfortunately, the client return a single object `Response` which extends `Iterable<Response>`. Hence, it's like a list. You'll need to manually form the `Map`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to iterate over the Response in order to get the map.

Here is an example for Map<String, String> with for loop:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String key : results.getKeys()) {
    map.put(key, results.get(key).toString());
}
```

Here is the same example but using java lambdas:

```
Map<String, String> map = result.getKeys().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key, key -> result.get(key).toString()));
```

For your case with json you can just change the transformation function from `.toString()` to something that suits your need.

Edit 1:

As HSCAN returns array as defined:

> return a two elements multi-bulk reply, where the first element is a
> string representing an unsigned 64 bit number (the cursor), and the
> second element is a multi-bulk with an array of elements.

There is not a simple solution to create a map but this is what I recommend:

```
Iterator<Response> iterator = response.get(1).stream().iterator();
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        map.put(iterator.next().toString(), iterator.next().toString());
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that the result form Redis is an array, not a Map

Comment: I have edited the answer and tested.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a simple `for`

```java
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i+=2) {
            result.put(source[i], source[i + 1]);
        }
```

In Kotlin you can use a more elegant solution but I think this one works